# How to edit or customize the look book in sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-administration

I am site admins (not farm admin) for a SP online hosted share point site, which was created using look book which is mentioned below.

https://lookbook.microsoft.com/details/e6e86025-a8fd-4e3e-bb2e-4578862edd8c

When the site was deployed, I see only side menu, but I dont see top menu.. I went into navigation and try to bring that up, but no luck.

How do i make sure we have side menu and top menu.

my idea is to have top menu for teams and sub teams, side menu for quick links which is different from top menu.

both menus have to flow all through the site.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the "TEAM COMMUNICATION SITE" look book has the hub site navigation feature.

[image]

Please register current site as a hub site via SharePoint admin center> Active sites, then re-provision the look book again.

[image]

Reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/create-hub-site#create-a-hub-site-in-the-new-sharepoint-admin-center

Comment: thank you, i used this suggestion